# want to view sql latest data in top and old data last. means latest to old

Tags: php

I make php form for sql data view. problem is i want view latest data in top and old data last. can some help me??
Here is my php form view code.
all details here for get data from sql. and its work fine, but in need view latest to old.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="datatable table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>S.No</th>
        <th class="wraper-title">Notice Title</th>
        <th>Publish Date</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>View</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
        <th>Download</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
      while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
     ?>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row"><?php echo $r['id'] ?></th>
        <td class="wraper-title"><?php echo $r['name'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r['date'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r['type'] ?></td>
        <td>
          <a type="button" class="btn btn-success" href="<?php echo $r['location'] ?>">View</a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete" title="Delete this notice" href="#" onclick='DeleteFile(<?php echo $r['id'] ?>)'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary download" href="<?php echo $r['location'] ?>" title="Download <?php echo $r['name'] ?>" download="<?php echo $r['name'] ?>" {%=file.thumbnailUrl?'data-gallery':''%}><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></i></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <?php
      }
      ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>S.No</th>
          <th class="wraper-title">Notice Title</th>
          <th>Publish Date</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>View</th>
          <th>Delete</th>
          <th>Download</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
   </table>
```

please help me

Comment: use Order by desc in your query  for example : "select * from users order by user_id desc"

Comment: Definitely sort this on the DB with SQL. You COULD sort it with PHP using an array_map but this is not the right place to do that. Additionally I saw someone post an answer using jQuery, again that's another level further down that you could use but the source of the issue in in your SQL and that's where you should resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this feature. This will order your first and second column in ascending order.

where 0 and 1 are index of your columns

```
$('#table_id').dataTable( {
    "order": [[ 0, 'asc' ], [ 1, 'asc' ]]
});
```